# How to autoapply a custom JPA converter for boolean to overwrite the default one?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, converters

In my application using JPA 2.2 / Hibernate 5.4, I would like to globally persist booleans in Oracle as CHAR(1) with J/N instead of Y/N.

I have a working Converter implementing AttributeConverter, but I struggle to get it globally to work.

`@Converter(autoApply = true)` does not work, apparently as the default one is already registered.

I would like avoid writing `@Convert(converter = BooleanJNStringConverter.class)` on each field, which may be forgotten by others.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats your database? Usually booleans are persisted as 0/1

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Booleans are usually converted to true/false on real databases ;) - PostgreSQL User here...

Comment: @Daniel MS SQL is not a real database? But still its not really clear what the usecase for OP is

Comment: Usecase is large legacy system with 50+ of booleans in J/N, wanting developers to write boolean without danger of forgetting a custom converter annotation for a case, which is not custom in the context of the system. Such a thing should be defined once IMHO.

Comment: In my case, working with a multi module Spring Boot app, the problem appeared because my converter was in a different module of the Spring Boot app. Unsurprisingly the EntityManager was not picking that converter because it was not in the list of packages that it scans by default. So, my guess, is that you should look at the list of packages your entity manager scans.